# Automate the tar on file creation

Tags: linux, automation, logging, tar

I need to tar the log files automatically when its get created with date (eg., error.log-20151116). How should i automate this activity. I don't want to perform this action by log rotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - Watch a folder and run a command when a file exists](http://superuser.com/questions/499638/linux-watch-a-folder-and-run-a-command-when-a-file-exists)

Comment: I think what you need is crontab. You can see how to use it with tar here: https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/automatic-backups-with-cron-tar-and-ssh/